# How to make <li> the same height as its <a> child?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the `li` the same size as the `a` child?

```
<ul class="ul1" id="list">
  <li class="li1" id="item1">
    <a class="a1" id="link1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li1" id="item2">
    <a class="a1" id="link2">Item Long 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see on the **gif** and **snippet** below that even with `height: auto`, the `<li>` is not expanding to be same `height` as its `<a>` child.

[image]

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
const link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
const description = document.getElementById('description');

description.innerHTML = `<b>ul height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(ul).height}
<b>li height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(item1).height}
<b>link height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(link1).height}`
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.li1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.a1 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background: lightblue;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

#description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1" id="list">
  <li class="li1" id="item1">
    <a class="a1" id="link1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li1" id="item2">
    <a class="a1" id="link2">Item Long 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="description"></p>
```

Comment: `display: block` on `a`?

Comment: Yes @kukkuz, but he also has to remove the padding. The `a` will be `18px` in height but because of `box-sizing: border-box;` 10 of those pixels we are reserved for the padding. The only way to force text into a smaller container is by setting a `height`.

Comment: `display: inline-block`, flex might cause issue when the number of child increase

Comment: @JoykalInfotech What worked better for me was indeed `display: inline-block` on the `<a>` tag. Would you write an answer suggesting that? Other suggestions might still work, but with `inline-block` I change only the behavior that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` on `<a>` would work better for you, without getting any other disturbance. 
read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 1):

Try display flex on `<li>`

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
const link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
const description = document.getElementById('description');

description.innerHTML = `<b>ul height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(ul).height}
<b>li height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(item1).height}
<b>link height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(link1).height}`
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.li1 {
  display:flex;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.a1 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background: lightblue;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

#description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1" id="list">
  <li class="li1" id="item1">
    <a class="a1" id="link1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li1" id="item2">
    <a class="a1" id="link2">Item Long 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="description"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding padding on your `a1` class which adds the spacing. I assume it's something like this you're wanting.

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
const link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
const description = document.getElementById('description');

description.innerHTML = `<b>ul height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(ul).height}
<b>li height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(item1).height}
<b>link height is:</b> ${window.getComputedStyle(link1).height}`
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.li1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.a1 {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background: lightblue;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

#description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1" id="list">
  <li class="li1" id="item1">
    <a class="a1" id="link1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li1" id="item2">
    <a class="a1" id="link2">Item Long 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="description"></p>
```

Comment: I do want the padding!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what the problem is then

Comment: `display: inline-block` did the trick. The `<li>` expands to include everything (padding and border also because I'm using `box-sizing: border-box`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use display **inline-flex** on `<li>` segment like :

```
.li1 {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```